# Pod not restarting after failed liveness probes for 'connection reset by peer'

Tags: kubernetes, livenessprobe

I've got the following pod which consistently failed liveness probes for 'connection reset by peer' and was marked unhealthy, but not restarted

```
146 Unhealthy: (combined from similar events): Liveness probe failed: Get "http://[ip address]:8080/q/health/live": read tcp [local node ip address]:54580->[ip address]:8080: read: connection reset by peer
```

It's only when http status 503 was returned, that the pod was restarted by the cluster. Is this expected behavior for kubernetes liveness probes, and a way to adjust for it to restart pods that are not accepting connections?

One thing to note is that the liveness config was set to a high interval, only one check every 30 secs. This has since been set more frequent. No successful probes were received during this timeframe of 5 hours where the pod was not restarted.

```
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 5
        httpGet:
          path: /q/health/live
          port: http
          scheme: HTTP
        periodSeconds: 30
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 30
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 5
        httpGet:
          path: /q/health/ready
          port: http
          scheme: HTTP
        periodSeconds: 30
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 30
        initialDelaySeconds: 15
```

pod part of a a deployment, not a replicaset, and no poddisruptionbudget present

expected: Pod restart after it was marked as unhealthy through the liveness config.
What happened: The failing pod was kept around for 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If the TCP connection with a peer across the network is closed by the peer or if it is closed unexpectedly,  error occurs.

To resolve this issue:

If you are trying to perform background work with CPU throttling, try using the ["CPU is always allocated"](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#setting) CPU allocation setting.

Ensure that you are within the [outbound requests timeouts.](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#outbound-timeout)  If your application maintains any connection in an idle state beyond this threshold, the gateway needs to reap the connection.

By default, the TCP socket option keepalive is disabled for Cloud Run. There is no direct way to configure the keepalive option in Cloud Run at the service level, but you can enable the keepalive option for each socket connection by providing the correct socket options when opening a new TCP socket connection, depending on the client library that you are using for this connection in your application.

Occasionally [outbound connections will be reset](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#outbound-reset) due to infrastructure updates. If your application reuses long-lived connections, then we recommend that you configure your application to re-establish connections to avoid the reuse of a dead connection.

Comment: In this case the issue why it failed liveness is known - the service itself became unresponsive to HTTP due to an internal crash. This is not the issue I'm after here.


I'm investigating why the pod was not restarted, despite marking the pod as unhealthy & logging the liveness failed status events, as it should according to the liveness probe specs.


Restarting was the correct approach, but it was not triggered by kubernetes until it returned 503 instead of connection reset by peer.



Failures can happen, but the fallback strategy was not triggered.

Comment: @AlexWauters, I have edited the answer accordingly. Can you please check and let me know whether it helped you? If not I am happy to assist you further.

Comment: Hi @srividya - I believe you may have linked Cloud Run documentation?
In this case I'm trying to figure out why Kubernetes (not on cloud run) is not triggering a restart after a failed liveness probe, which is the mitigating action I'm trying to apply.